# Groovy String to Date

Tags: string, parsing, date, groovy

I am coding this with Groovy

I am currently trying to convert a string that I have to a date without having to do anything too tedious.

```
String theDate = "28/09/2010 16:02:43";
def newdate = new Date().parse("d/M/yyyy H:m:s", theDate)
```

Output:

```
Tue Aug 10 16:02:43 PST 2010
```

The above code works just fine, however when my string changes to something like:

```
String testDate = "Tue Aug 10 16:02:43 PST 2010"
def newerdate = new Date().parse("d/M/yyyy H:m:s", testDate)
```

It tells me that "there is no such value for Tue". I tried to throw an 'E' in the parse for the date but it said the date was not able to be parsed.

Can someone explain how I should go about parsing the second example?

Comment: This helps me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17450946/2835520

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The first argument to parse() is the expected format. You have to change that to `Date.parse("E MMM dd H:m:s z yyyy", testDate)` for it to work. (Note you don't need to create a new Date object, it's a static method)

If you don't know in advance what format, you'll have to find a special parsing library for that. In Ruby there's a library called [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/), but I'm not aware of a Groovy equivalent. **Edit**: There is a Java port of the library called [jChronic](https://github.com/samtingleff/jchronic), you might want to check it out.

Comment: As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by DateFormat.parse(String s)

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel, it's rather about Groovy `Date`, my friend.

Comment: From 2.5.0, however, there has been a breaking change and those enhancements are not shipped anymore with groovy-all.

So, going forward, they need to be included as a separate module, named groovy-dateutil. [See here.](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-string-to-date)

Answer (score 28):

Try this:

```
def date = Date.parse("E MMM dd H:m:s z yyyy", dateStr)
```

Here are the [patterns to format the dates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: `Date.parse` is **deprecated**. Use `DateFormat.parse()` instead.

Comment: I know this is old, but `Date.parse(String, String)` is [not deprecated in groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.4/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (which is the language used here if I am to believe the question's tags).

Comment: There is an online date format tester, which I found useful http://sdfonlinetester.info/#

Answer (score 24):

JChronic is your best choice.  Here's an example that adds a `.fromString()` method to the Date class that parses just about anything you can throw at it:

```
Date.metaClass.'static'.fromString = { str ->
    com.mdimension.jchronic.Chronic.parse(str).beginCalendar.time
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
println Date.fromString("Tue Aug 10 16:02:43 PST 2010")
println Date.fromString("july 1, 2012")
println Date.fromString("next tuesday")
```

Answer (score 7):

`Date#parse` is deprecated . The alternative is :

```
java.text.DateFormat#parse
```

thereFore :

```
 new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd H:m:s z yyyy", Locale.ARABIC).parse(testDate)
```

#### Note that SimpleDateFormat is an implementation of DateFormat

Comment: He is not using parse(String) but parse(format, date) which comes from groovy not java. This method is not deprecated.

Comment: Wrong API function: you mention: java Date.parse(String), question is about: Groovy Date.parse(String, String), which isn't deprecated!

Answer (score 5):

Googling around for Groovy ways to "cast" a `String` to a `Date`, I came across this article:
http://www.goodercode.com/wp/intercept-method-calls-groovy-type-conversion/

The author uses Groovy metaMethods to allow dynamically extending the behavior of any class' `asType` method. Here is the code from the website.

```
class Convert {
    private from
    private to

    private Convert(clazz) { from = clazz }
    static def from(clazz) {
        new Convert(clazz)
    }

    def to(clazz) {
        to = clazz
        return this
    }

    def using(closure) {
        def originalAsType = from.metaClass.getMetaMethod('asType', [] as Class[])
        from.metaClass.asType = { Class clazz ->
            if( clazz == to ) {
                closure.setProperty('value', delegate)
                closure(delegate)
            } else {
                originalAsType.doMethodInvoke(delegate, clazz)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

They provide a `Convert` class that wraps the Groovy complexity, making it trivial to add custom `as`-based type conversion from any type to any other:

```
Convert.from( String ).to( Date ).using { new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy').parse(value) }

def christmas = '12-25-2010' as Date
```

It's a convenient and powerful solution, but I wouldn't recommend it to someone who isn't familiar with the tradeoffs and pitfalls of tinkering with metaClasses.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best easy way in this case is to use [parseToStringDate](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parseToStringDate(java.lang.String)) which is part of GDK (Groovy JDK enhancements):

> Parse a String matching the pattern EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy
> containing US-locale-constants only (e.g. Sat for Saturdays). Such a
> string is generated by the toString method of Date

Example:

```
println(Date.parseToStringDate("Tue Aug 10 16:02:43 PST 2010").format('MM-dd-yyyy'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way we are going within our developing application.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

String newDateAdded = "2018-11-11T09:30:31"
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
Date dateAdded = dateFormat.parse(newDateAdded)

println(dateAdded)
```

The output looks like

```
Sun Nov 11 09:30:31 GMT 2018
```

In your example, we could adjust a bit to meet your need. If I were you, I will do:

```
String datePattern = "d/M/yyyy H:m:s"
String theDate = "28/09/2010 16:02:43"
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern)
println df.parse(theDate)
```

I hope this would help you much.