# convert date string to date in grails rich-ui datechooser

Tags: date, grails, rich-ui

I have used rich ui's date chooser.
I get the value of date correct.
But if I want to set the value of richui's datechooser how is that done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to parse the date manually in your controller because your format/pattern is unknown to grails.

```
def date = Date().parse("MM-dd-yyyy", params.date); //<-- consider using a constant for the date format
```

or reset the params value to the java.util.Date class.

```
params.date = Date().parse("MM-dd-yyyy", params.date);  //<-- re-assigns date string as date class
```

You might also want test the inbound format to make sure someone doesn't manually enter an invalid format...

```
def date = (parmas.date.matches("\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}"))? Date().parse("MM-dd-yyyy", params.date) : null; //<-- safely return null if doesn't match a date regex.
```

see also:

- [Groovy String to Date - Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817862/groovy-string-to-date)
- [Jira feature request
  (won't fix but, suggests custom DataBinder)](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-4881)

Comment: Yeah that works Thanks. but it seems I have problem in setting the date in richui's datechooser box.

Comment: You'll most likely have to format the string back into a date in your GSP if the RichUi requires a date and not a string.