# Jodatime date format

Tags: java, date, jodatime, date-format

Is it possible to format JodaTime Date.

Here is the code:

```
   private static LocalDate priorDay(LocalDate date1) {
      do {
         date1 = date1.plusDays(-1);
      } while (date1.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY ||
             date1.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY); 
      //System.out.print(date1);
      return date1;
   }
```

Here date1 returns as: **2013-07-02** but i would like as **02-JUL-13**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13):

> Is it possible to format JodaTime Date

Yes. You want [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yy")
    .withLocale(Locale.US); // Make sure we use English month names
String text = formatter.format(date1);
```

That will give 02-Jul-13, but you can always upper-case it.

See the [Input and Output](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Input_and_Output) part of the user guide for more information.

EDIT: Alternatively, as suggested by Rohit:

```
String text = date1.toString("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.US);
```

Personally I'd prefer to create the formatter once, as a constant, and reuse it everywhere you need it, but it's up to you.

Comment: I think you mistyped `MM` instead of `MMM` there.

Comment: @JonSkeet.. Out of curiousity, Will there be any issue, apart from the `Locale`, if I used `toString("dd-MMM-yy")`, instead of `DateTimeFormatter.format()`?

Comment: @RohitJain: Probably not - and you can specify the locale separately. It may be more efficient to create the format once though, and it's more reusable too.

Comment: Appreciated. But, how do we uppercase it. Is it just date1.toUpperCase or "dd-mmm-yy"?

Comment: @user2501165: You've got to call `toUpperCase` on a *string* - the idea of calling it on a date makes no sense. So basically take the output of either `formatter.format(date1)` or `date1.toString("dd-MMM-yy")` and call `toUpperCase(Locale.US)` on that result. Or build a custom locale which uses all-upper-case month names, of course.

Comment: Actually found a easy way to do it. Yes i had to call toUpperCase() though ie: String text = date1.toString("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.US).toUpperCase();

Comment: @user2501165: Well yes, that's what I was suggesting - although I'd include the locale in the `toUpperCase` call as well. I don't *think* it'll actually matter as there are no months with an "i" in the first three letters, but it's a good habit to get into unless you want your code to behave unexpectedly in Turkey...

Comment: re "prefer to create the formatter once" - joda caches the formatter, so it doesn't create the same one again. No need to keep a reference to it in your code.

Comment: @uval: Interesting - although I would personally prefer to do it as a constant anyway, to ensure that you're using the same format everywhere.

Comment: I use String constants with the desired pattern for that :)

Comment: @uval: But that doesn't express what you really want - the same *format* applied all the time - as clearly, IMO. What do you see as the *disadvantage* of creating the formatter once and reusing it?

Comment: Nothing critical - just less reference redundancy. The String pattern is used as a key to exactly the same *format* object, so the same format will be applied. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @uval: Not sure what you mean by "reference redundancy" here. When I've got code which wants to format a date as text, I want a formatter - I don't want a string which I can use to *get* a formatter. That's an extra step in the code using the formatter for no benefit.

Comment: Ok, in my case I have several formatters for different cases, so (key,value) pairs make the code cleaner. If you use just one or two, you're approach is more appropriate.

Comment: @uval: But if you've got key/value pairs, why can't the pairs be the formatters? However you're currently referring to the patterns, just make that refer to the formatters themselves...

Comment: the key/value pairs are indeed <string,formatter>. My point is that it is provided anyway by joda's cache. So I can keep only the keys as constants in my code. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @uval: Not a lot, to be honest - but I think this is getting somewhat offtopic.

Answer (score 9):

Check out the Joda [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

You probably want to use it via something like:

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime();
 DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
 String str = fmt.print(dt);
```

This is a much better solution than the existing [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class. The Joda variant is thread-safe. The old Java variant is (counterintuitively) *not* thread-safe!