# Convert a string in yyyyMM format to a date in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a `String` of `yyyyMM` format and I need to convert it to a date in the format `MM/yyyy`.

Example: String is `201710` and it needs to be converted to a date in the format `10/2017`.

Can someone tell me how to do this in [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy)?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy String to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817862/groovy-string-to-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as `java.util.Date` object in specific format. Format of the date like `yyyyMM` or `MM/yyyy` is just a way it is represented as a `String`. If your input is a String formatted as `201710` and you want to format it as `10/2017` then you have to create a `java.util.Date` object from your input String (`Date.parse()` method does that) and call `.format('MM/yyyy')` method on that created object, e.g.

```
def formatted = Date.parse("yyyyMM", "201710").format("MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: I set the current date to the formatted value (10/2017)  using acalendar.setTime(formatted)  and then tried to get the month using int month =acalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH). This returns an error ' Cannot cast object '10/2017' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date' '. Is there a way to convert 'formatted ' to Date ?

Comment: Following part creates `java.util.Date` object - `Date.parse("yyyyMM", "201710")`. If you want to pass it to `Calendar.setTime()` then don't call `.format("MM/yyyy")` on this object, because this method returns a `String`.

Comment: Yes, it works now. Date formatted = Date.parse("yyyyMM", "201710")  acalendar.setTime(formatted) Thanks Szymon !